# PostgreSQL failed with vacuum and autovacuum

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

Postgres v11.9

There are many errors on Postgres log like this:

```
    2020-09-05 17:35:37 GMT [22464]: @: [6-1] ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 636700836 from before xid cutoff 809126794 needs to be frozen
2020-09-05 17:35:37 GMT [22464]: @: [7-1] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "table_nane"
```

Manual vacuum fails with this error too.

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Export the database with `pg_dump`.
- Create a new database cluster and restore the dump into it.
- Remove the original database cluster.

Comment: yep, the only way I`ve found